# Displaying only selected items from ListBox in new List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

I'm relatively fresh to WPF and discovering XAML.

I've got one `ListBox Name="EmployeeTitles"` in XAML (shown below). For the purpose of demonstrating the problem `DataContext = employees` which is `ObservableCollection<Employee>`.

```
        <ListBox Name="EmployeeTitles"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            SelectionMode="Extended">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
                            <!--StackPanel will have more items-->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                            </StackPanel>                         
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My "Code Behind" class snippet looks as follows:

```
private string _title;
public string Title
{
    get { return _title; }
    set
    {
        _title = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private bool _isSelected;
public bool IsSelected
{
    get
    {
        return _isSelected;
    }
    set
    {
        _isSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I would like to show the selected items in a different control. For example have a list that shows only selected items. Can I somehow mark in XAML that I only only want to display items with `IsChecked="True"`? I know I could have another ObservableCollection storing only selected items and updating it in "Code Behind" whenever property `IsSelected` changes, but that seems like an overhead and I suppose there should be a way to do it in XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the other listbox with the selecteditems of the original listbox. Try the below code.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListBox x:Name="Emp" ItemsSource="{Binding EmpCollection}" SelectionMode="Extended">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
                            <!--StackPanel will have more items-->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox x:Name="SelectedEmp" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Emp,Path=SelectedItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}


class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Emp> EmpCollection { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        EmpCollection = new ObservableCollection<Emp>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            EmpCollection.Add(new Emp() {Title = "Title"+i});
        }
    }

}

class Emp:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't bind `ListBox.SelectedItems`.

Comment: I stand corrected. That's very cool. You still have to get them back to the viewmodel somehow, though.